# For how long client application waiting for web service response, and what if response never come?

Tags: c#, web-services

For example if we have client application that call web service, and waiting to get response from server.
What if response never come ?
What will happen with client application?
Application break, throws some exception or waiting for ever?
I am talking about desktop client application(windows forms) that use web service.

Comment: That is for you to decide - specify a timeout and create rules what to do if the query timed out.

Comment: How? this is my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477476/how-to-be-sure-that-my-application-will-not-break-in-case-if-web-service-is-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't added functionality to handle a time out your client app will continue to wait/hang. Your client app should handle errors returning and server timeouts.

E.g. Jquery error and timeout handling.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: I am talking about desktop client application(windows forms) that use web service.

Comment: Can you get access to the .Timeout property on the service call and use svc.Timeout

Comment: This is my better question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477476/how-to-be-sure-that-my-application-will-not-break-in-case-if-web-service-is-not

Answer (score 1):

It depends, what are you using to call the web service? Is it an AJAX request? If you're using jQuery as an example, you can pass to $.ajax() a timeout option, and specify an error callback that's triggered when the timeout expires.

Comment: I am talking about desktop client application(windows forms) that use web service.