# How to be sure that my application will not break in case if web service is not reachable?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have web service that get some status.
I want be sure that my application will not break in case if web service is not reachable (for example if there in no connection)
How to do that ?
I ping web service in timer at every 10 seconds. (windows forms application)

This is my first idea, but probably not good.

```
private void getStatusTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Get status from web service:
        MyStatus currentStatus = WebService_GetStatus();
        //Do something with status
    }
    catch
    {
       //Do nothing if breaks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can make use of Circuit Breaker pattern , in which it always do check circuit is close to make call or not. if the circuit is open it set status of circuit to open and check sometime later i.e. after define time or when new call is there.

But if the circuit it open it return you the circuit is open and you have to try after some time later

You can see pattern implementation here :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589784.aspx

You can also check martin flower post regarding this pattern : http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html

[image]